# Comparators and HashMaps for Markov Chain

Tags: java, hashmap, processing, comparator, comparable

I am trying to make a markov chain in Java/Processing, that will read a book then be able to cut it up in probabilistic ways. Programming is a hobby…

I had the idea that the way to do it was to use a HashMap, and store a Word Object within it. I could easily do this with a String, but within each unique Word it needs to have another HashMap that will store more yet more Word Objects for the Words that follow it, and so on until we have made a model with a sufficient level of complexity.

The problems are that I can’t seem to be able to check whether or not a Word Object is already within the Map by its `String name`.

Through looking around on SO I can see that it is likely that I will need a Comparator — but all the examples that I have seen use `compare` or `compareTo`, when I think that I need something that is more like `equals`? I don’t need anything at all to do with Sorting, the order will be worked out in the second part of the program.

The code below is pretty horrible — I have been hacking away at this problem for ages but I can’t find an explanation that is sufficiently dumbed down enough for me to understand it.

In Pseudo:
`read book
If the Word is not in the Map, put it in there
If the Word is in the Map, iterate the key
Check the Words that follow this Word, and check in the same way if they are within the first Word’s Map, adding as necessary… repeat…`

When this is complete
`Using the Integer values as probabilities, pick a word
from that Word’s Map, find a Word that is probable to follow it
repeat until desired length is achieved`

Code so far:

```
///markovs

import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Comparator;

HashMap<Word, Integer> book;

void setup()
{

  book = new HashMap<Word, Integer>();
  String[] rows = loadStrings("crash.txt");
  for (int i = 0; i < rows.length; i++)
  {
    if (trim(rows[i]).length() == 0)
    {
      continue;
    }

    String[] pieces = split(rows[i], " ");

    for (int j = 0; j<pieces.length; j++)
    {

      Word temp = new Word(pieces[j]);

      //c++;
      if (book.compare(temp)) {
        println("this worked for once");
        //iterate here
      } else {
        book.put(temp, 1);
        println("didn’t work");
        //book.add(temp);
        book.put(temp, 1);
      }
    }
  }
  println(book.size());
  //println(c);
  //println(book);
}

class WordComparator implements Comparator<Word> {
  @Override
  public int compare(Word w1, Word w2) {
    String w1name = w1.name;
    String w2name = w2.name;

    if (w1name.equals(w2name)) {
      return 1;
    } else {
      return 0;
    }
  }
}

class Word
{
  String name;
  int value=1; 
  int depth;

  HashMap<String, Integer> list;

  Word(String name_)
  {
    this.name = name_;
  }

  int compareTo(Word w) {
    if (w.name.equals(this.name)) {
      return 0;
    } else {
      return -1;
    }
  }

  Word(Word w)
  {
    this.depth = w.depth+1;
  }

  void nextWord(String word)
  {
  }
  void count() {
    value++;
  }
  void makeHash()
  {
    list = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
  }
}
```

Comment: You are doing a `compare` between a `book`, which is a `HashMap`, and `temp`, which is a `Word`. That's probably not what you want to do.

Comment: To point out something that seems to be ignored in the answers so far: You should *carefully* think about whether a `Word` with `name="foo", value=1` should or should *not* be "equal" to a `Word` with `name="foo", value=12345` ....

Comment: A related discussion in Processing's forum http://forum.processing.org/two/discussion/7691/generating-hashcode-questions

Answer (score 0):

To use an Object as a key in a HashMap, you need to override two methods: `equals()` and `hashCode()`. I'm not exactly sure what you're going for, but a simple example that just uses the `name` variable would look like this:

```
public boolean equals(Object other){
   if(other instanceof Word){
      return this.name.equals(((Word)other).name);
   }
   return false;
}

public int hashCode(){
   return name.hashCode();
}
```

However, if you're just using the `name` variable anyway, you might be looking for a **multimap**, which is just a Map that contains a Map that contains...

```
HashMap<String, HashMap<String, Integer>> bookMap;
```

Furthermore, while `HashMap` does not use the `compareTo` function, the way you've implemented it seems off. First of all, you need to implement Comparable on your class:

```
class Word implements Comparable<Word>{
```

And secondly, the `compareTo` function should return one of 3 values: negative, zero, or positive. Right now you're only returning zero or negative, which doesn't make any sense.

I think you might be better off taking a step back and describing what you're actually trying to do, as your code contains a lot of confusing logic right now.

Answer (score 0):

As for comparing, you can override Object's inherited equals method, something like:

```
  @ Override 
   boolean equals(Object o) {
    return o instanceof Word
      ? o.name.equals(name) : false;
  }
```

Answer (score -1):

Be aware of using your own types as keys for the `HashMap`, in this case `Word`. That only works out well if you provide a sensible implementation of `.hashCode()` and `.equals()` on `Word`.

Here it looks like you could just use `String` instead. `String` already has the required method implementations. If you really do want to use `Word`, you could use those methods from String. e.g.

```
class Word {
    String letters;

    public int hashCode() {
        return letters.hashCode();
    }

    public boolean equals(Object o) {
         if (o == null || o.getClass() != getClass()) return false;
         return letters.equals(((Word) o).letters);
    }
}
```

You don't need a `compare` or `compareTo`, just these two.

Comment: The `equals()` function takes an Object parameter, not a Word parameter.

Comment: And now your edited answer will throw an NPE if `o` is null.

Comment: And **now** your edited answer will not work with subclasses.